# Use group_by and case_when to produce single value per group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame with `id` and `stage`. `stage` is character but corresponds to an ordered process (A -> B -> C -> ...).

```
expand.grid(id=c(1:5), stage = LETTERS[1:4]) %>%
 arrange(id) %>%
 mutate(flag = case_when(str_detect(stage, "D") ~ "Dance",
                         str_detect(stage, "C") ~ "Climb",
                         str_detect(stage, "B") ~ "Biceps",
                         str_detect(stage, "A") ~ "Aerobic"))
```

This produces what I would expect, a vectorized case by case flag column. But what I want is the output of my `case_when` to be unique for the whole group of `id`. So I tried adding `group_by(id)`

```
expand.grid(id=c(1:5), stage = LETTERS[1:4]) %>%
 arrange(id) %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(flag = case_when(str_detect(stage, "D") ~ "Dance",
                         str_detect(stage, "C") ~ "Climb",
                         str_detect(stage, "B") ~ "Biceps",
                         str_detect(stage, "A") ~ "Aerobic"))
```

But this doesn't change the nature of the result. Changing `mutate` into `summarize` does not produce the "summarizing" effect I was hoping for either.
It's likely that I don't fully understand the functioning of `case_when()` and `group_by()` and thus I'm not able to write the proper command to get the summary I'm looking for.

My expected output should have `id`, `stage` being the last stage in the order and `flag` according to that stage.

```
     id stage flag 
  <int> <fct> <chr>
1     1 D     Dance
2     2 D     Dance
3     3 D     Dance
4     4 D     Dance
5     5 D     Dance
```

To be more clear, let's assume `id` 1 and 2 are in stage A, 3 in B, 4 in C, and 5 in D.

```
toy <- expand.grid(id=c(1:5), stage = LETTERS[1:4]) %>%
 arrange(id) %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(flag = case_when(str_detect(stage, "D") ~ "Dance",
                         str_detect(stage, "C") ~ "Climb",
                         str_detect(stage, "B") ~ "Biceps",
                         str_detect(stage, "A") ~ "Aerobic"))
# grabbing only some of them
toy <- toy[c(1, 5, 10, 15, 20),]
```

Output should look like this:

```
     id stage flag   
  <int> <fct> <chr>  
1     1 A     Aerobic
2     2 A     Aerobic
3     3 B     Biceps 
4     4 C     Climb  
5     5 D     Dance
```

I'm fine with repeated `id`, I can summarize from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `any` (and the order of operations within `case_when` to get the `flag` that you want, within a `summarize`. We need to add a little in order to preserve `stage`.

```r
expand.grid(id=c(1:5), stage = LETTERS[1:4]) %>%
  arrange(id) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(
   stage = intersect(c("D","C","B","A"), stage)[1],
   flag = case_when(any(str_detect(stage, "D")) ~ "Dance",
                    any(str_detect(stage, "C")) ~ "Climb",
                    any(str_detect(stage, "B")) ~ "Biceps",
                    any(str_detect(stage, "A")) ~ "Aerobic")
  )
# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#      id stage flag 
#   <int> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 D     Dance
# 2     2 D     Dance
# 3     3 D     Dance
# 4     4 D     Dance
# 5     5 D     Dance
```

However, an alternative using `left_join` that avoids the piece-wise operation of `case_when`.

```r
acronyms <- data.frame(
  prio  = 1:4,
  stage = c("D", "C", "B", "A"),
  flag  = c("Dance", "Climb", "Biceps", "Aerobic")
)

expand.grid(id=c(1:5), stage = LETTERS[1:4]) %>%
  left_join(acronyms) %>%
  arrange(id, prio) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  select(-prio) %>%
  ungroup()
```

The basic `stage`/`flag` association in `acronyms` is mostly sufficient; I added `prio` for a deterministic and simple way of always getting the most-important for each `id`. There may be other useful tricks here depending on your ultimate need.

Comment: I was about to comment on the intersect approach and I like the `left_join` approach much better, looks like a more canonical way of doing it

Comment: the `intersect` was merely to find the most-desirable stage and keep it (order of the first vector is important); it was replaced by `prio` in the join option.

Comment: This is what needs to occur to use `case_when` and `group_by` together?  I'm grouping by a vector containing thousands of unique values. Seems very "un-tidyverse"